# Buscar registro en Web Service Java

Tags: java, webservice, web, crud

estoy comenzando con esto del Web Service Rest y me he encontrado con el problema al hacer un crud con la base de datos.

Por ejemplo, necesito buscar un registro pero no por su PK sino que por otro campo, es posible hacer esto? podrían guiarme en como hacerlo? he buscado pero todo es muy confuso

Ayuda please!

Esta es una de las clases mapeadas desde la BD Oracle, no estoy usando frameworks, solo las creo con RestFull Web Services from Database.

En esta clase, necesito filtrar por correo y clave...

```
package entidad.servicio;

import entidad.Usuario;
import java.util.List;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.DELETE;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.PUT;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Stateless
@Path("entidad.usuario")
public class UsuarioFacadeREST extends AbstractFacade<Usuario> {

@PersistenceContext(unitName = "WSPU")
private EntityManager em;

public UsuarioFacadeREST() {
    super(Usuario.class);
}

@POST
@Override
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public void create(Usuario entity) {
    super.create(entity);
}

@PUT
@Path("{id}")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public void edit(@PathParam("id") Short id, Usuario entity) {
    super.edit(entity);
}

@DELETE
@Path("{id}")
public void remove(@PathParam("id") Short id) {
    super.remove(super.find(id));
}

@GET
@Path("{id}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Usuario find(@PathParam("id") Short id) {
    return super.find(id);
}

@GET
@Override
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public List<Usuario> findAll() {
    return super.findAll();
}

@GET
@Path("{from}/{to}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public List<Usuario> findRange(@PathParam("from") Integer from,   
@PathParam("to") Integer to) {
    return super.findRange(new int[]{from, to});
}
@GET
@Path("count")
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public String countREST() {
    return String.valueOf(super.count());
}

@Override
protected EntityManager getEntityManager() {
    return em;
   }

}
```

Comment: A tu pregunta, sí, sí se puede, pero deberías poner el código y con que frameworks estás trabajando para poder ayudarte

Comment: @Alberto agregué el codigo de una clase mapeada, por si puedes ayudarme por favor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La clase abstracta `AbstractFacade` te crea lo básico para acceder a la entidad de tu base de datos. Si quieres alguna otra consulta mas específica tienes que creártela tú. Suponiendo que tienes tu clase `Usuario` anotada con `@Entity` y añadida al `persistence.xml`, podrías hacere lo siguiente:

```
private List<Usuario> findUsuarioByField(EntityManager em, String value) {
    return em.createQuery("SELECT u FROM Usuario u where u.field = :value")
        .setParameter("value", value).getResultList();
}
```

Te he puesto **field**, tanto en el nombre del método como en la consulta (JPQL) porque no sé por qué campo vas a filtrar.

Mi recomendación: saca todas tus consultas a la clase `Usuario`. De esa forma lo tendrás todo centralizado en un único sitio. `AbstractFacade` no te aporta demasiado como para usarla (en mi opinión). Si finalmente decides llevar a cabo mi recomendación, solo tendrías que llevar el método anterior a la clase `Usuario` y ponerlo como `public static` en lugar de `private` y solamente tendrías que invocarlo así: `Usuario.findUsuarioByField`

Comment: Muchas gracias @Alberto era justo lo que buscaba, me fue de mucha utilidad